# JS and jQuery, executing fade function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question I guess. I want to execute the jQuery fade function in the loop on every array element.

Code:

```js
var dlugosc = 5;
dlugosc = dlugosc*1000;

var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
      // here I'd like to execute this function like this: x[i].fadeOut(500);
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    // and here like this: x[slideIndex-1].fadeIn(500);
    setTimeout(carousel, dlugosc);
}
```

How can I do such thing? Thanks

**UPDATE**

it works:
`$(".slides")[i].style.display = "none";`

so, why doesn't it work?
`$(".slides")[i].fadeOut(500);`

Comment: With jQuery you can run it on more than one element. But I am not sure what are you trying to achive?

Comment: Do you just want `$(".slides").fadeOut(500)`? (fade out everything in class `.slides` all at the same time)

Comment: I just want to add fade effect to my very simple slider

Comment: So when you change image it should change with fade effect?

Comment: Yes, change with fade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work.  I used a promise object to ensure that all the animations are done for ".slides", because if I simply used a callback it would invoke the callback once per slide, kind of making the entire animation pointless.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(".slides").hide();
var waitTime = 1 * 1000;
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    $(".slides").fadeOut(250).promise().done(function () {
        $(".slides").eq(slideIndex++ % $(".slides").length).fadeIn(250);
    });
    setTimeout(carousel, waitTime);
}

</script>
```

**Update to respond to poster's question**:

$(".slides") is a jQuery object and can be modified in any jQuery-like fashion (so, fadeIn works).  Where as $(".slides")[0] fetches the first instance of .slides but as a **JavaScript dom object** which does **not** have access to any of jQuery's functions.  However, if you do $(".slides").eq(0) then you are fetching the first element as a **jQuery object**.  Then you can do $(".slides").eq(0).fadeIn(500);

Comment: Now, I've got photos one under this first one and those all fade at the same time

Comment: Could you update your question with the HTML?  It would make easier for me visualize what you're saying.

Comment: I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Example of vanillaJs `fadeIn/fadeOut` implementation.
*<sub>Just to understand, how it works at all.</sub>*

```js
function fade(el, time, fadeout) {
  var iterations = 25; // 25 steps of fade
  var counter = iterations;
  if (!fadeout) { // fadein will initialize a slide
    el.style.display = 'block';
    el.style.opacity = '0';
  }
  return new Promise(function(end){ // Promise used to determine animation end
    var t = setInterval(iteration, time/iterations);
    function iteration(){
      if (!--counter) { // end of animation
        clearInterval(t); // stop interval
        if (fadeout) el.style.display = 'none'; // hide a slide
        return end(); // resolve a Promise
      }
      el.style.opacity = fadeout ? counter/iterations : 1 - counter/iterations; // calculate current step opacity
    }
  });
}

function getCarousel(elements, fadeTime) {
  var index = elements.length-1;
  var len = elements.length;
  return function carousel() {
    return fade(elements[index], fadeTime, true)    
      .then(function(){
        index = (index + 1) % len;
        return fade(elements[index], fadeTime, false)
      });
  };
}
/*****/
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
var carousel = getCarousel(slides, 500);
carousel();
setInterval(carousel, 2000);
```

```css
.slides {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slides">Slide 1</div>
<div class="slides">Slide 2</div>
<div class="slides">Slide 3</div>
<div class="slides">Slide 4</div>
```